# Can you add an array without square brackets or subscript to an integer? What is the result?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I was going through an online lecture and I saw this function to sum an array

```
int arraySum(int array[], const int n)
    {
        int sum = 0, *ptr;
        int *const arrayEnd = array + n;
        ...
    }
```

I've not seen an array added to an integer before. If n is the size of the array, does array + n mean that arrayEnd is assigned a value of the last element in array[] or does it mean something else like the address of that element?

Comment: in C `x[a]` is the very same as `*(x+a)`

Comment: Well, first of all, there's no "array" here. In function parameter lists `int array[]` is implicitly transformed into `int *array`. So, from the very beginning `array` is a *pointer*. If `array` were an actual *array*, it would too decay to a pointer in this context. But in your example it is not needed, since `array` is already a pointer.

Comment: @AnT: An array declaration in a function paramter is not a pointer from the very beginning. First it is an array declaration, and then it is adjusted to a pointer. One difference is that the element type for an array must be complete (and this is not required for a pointer), and some compilers will enforce this.

Comment: @AnT: For example, [`int a[][]` is rejected while `int (*a)[]` is accepted](https://godbolt.org/z/zgIkKh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're seeing is pointer arithmetic.

`array` is a pointer to the start of your array.  Assuming the array has `n` elements, then `array + n` (or equivalently `&array[n]`) points to one element past the end of the array.

It is legal to have a pointer to one element past the end of an array, however you can't dereference that pointer.

Answer (score 1):

`void f(int array[])` and `void f(int* array)` are the same thing in C. So you're almost right when you speculate that it's the address of the last element: it's one past that. Meaning it's useful for less than checks, but not to dereference as that might crash or result in a garbage value.